# Extract files from Android system image?

Tags: adb, fastboot

Is it possible to extract files directly from an Android system.img file or do I need to load the system.img to a device first and then adb pull the file from the device?

Comment: Dunno. Still, +0 for now. Why would you want to extract files from an Android system image? Which files do you want? Please [edit] your question and enlighten us.

Comment: Just want to extract an executable from one system image to include in another. Ended up just flashing the system image then using adb pull. Thought there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools to extract that; however, not all files named system.img have the same format, so there's no guarantee that it could be done. Nevertheless, check out the tool I've been personally using: [LINK](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=57742855&postcount=40). This is meant to extract system.new.dat files introduced in Android 5.x, but also includes system.img capability.

Comment: In your experience, unpacking/repacking a non-custom ROM for purposes of removing bloatware, is it easier to do at that stage, instead of after it's installed? I mean just deleting those system apps, putting the whole thing back and flashing that. This is for those pesky ones that cause bootloops if you remove them *afterwards*

Comment: @Emil I always have them removed before they have a chance to create a mess in `/data`. It doesn't have to be done using the "unpack and repack" way though - for example, I have a simple flashable zip that contains a script that adds what I want and removes what I don't. After flashing a ROM and before booting, I'd just flash this additional package. This is of course based on that you already know what you want to remove, though.

Comment: Wow, that is *so* much better than unpack/repack way! Could you please share the script and a way of making this zip. Or create question/answer if it's better. I'm sure a lot of people will appreciate this and find it very useful. Thanks!

Comment: @Emil Actually I got my zip from XDA and modified it quite a bit, though it's been 2 years I can't really find the original anymore... The Edify script language is fairly straightforward, you should be able to sort it out quickly. In the meantime, let me see how I should share this with you... I'll probably strip it down and have it uploaded to my AFH later.

Comment: That would be awesome! I mean as long as it has one or two working examples. And how to make the zip so that TWRP would install it, that would be sufficient. I've been trying to remove some packages, and though I can do it while the system is running, after I reboot it never boots. But right after I remove those things the phone becomes sooo fast. I fail to see how something like Updater being removed can prevent the system from booting, unless there's a specific intention to do so from the manufacturer...

Comment: @Emil Grab the sample [here](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=889764386195918068). It contains examples of removing files, extracting files from within the zip to a destination, and executing a custom script. The magic is largely in `META-INF\com\google\android\updater-script` - give it a read and you should get the basics. Again, this is all based on that you already know what you want to remove and where they are located.

Comment: Thanks tested it out and it works as expected, very useful tool. Although if I run it after installing OS, it switches off the screen and the only way to turn it back on, is reboot. So I have to be careful when rebooting to boot into TWRP again and do install again.

Comment: @Emil Hmm? This script is meant for custom recoveries only. Don't run from within the OS.

Comment: I ran it from TWRP via its Install function. So Install OS, then run the script, and it blacks out the screen. Seems it's not a shutdown though, because holding buttons to go into recovery takes quicker from power-down state. But if I reboot and (before going into OS) go back to TWRP, then using Install again on the script, everything goes smoothly. Maybe it's just my device's peculiarity.